# Trying to copy two files with uppercase and lowercase extentions. Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows

Trying to copy two files with uppercase and lowercase extentions. example: textfile.txt, and textfile.TXT. was copied onto a dvd from linux. but when trying to copy to windows it cannot copy the lowercase file. when trying to copy one it copies the textfile.TXT instead of textfile.txt and if you allow it to copy both and select "do not overwrite" or "overwrite" you always end up with textfile.TXT. cannot get textfile.txt to copy. Also tried command prompt copying, in explorer, tried to send with filezilla. Nothing. I always end up with textfile.TXT. Searched everywhere and cannot find a response. This is a customers machine and i would prefer not to install software but im at the end of the plank with no ideas.

Comment: You'll have to rename one of the files. Linux is case-sensitive (`Temp.txt` is not the same as `tEmp.TXT`), but Windows is not (`Temp.txt` is exactly the same as `tEmp.TXT` or `TEMP.TXT`).

Comment: Whilst I agree with @KenWhite I just ask myself: I always thought it is the linux file systems being case sensitive, not the kernel (which is anyway) or the file handling system routines. So what happens if you use a linux file system in MS-Windoze?

Comment: I am aware of the fact that they are different... I shouldve clarified. if i no longer have access to a linux device. i cannot use it to rename the files. I was hoping there would be a workaround in the windows environment.

Comment: Windows is case-sensitive but the file is still on the DVD.  You could try something like IsoBuster (or any tool that works with DVDs or ISO images).  If it can't browse to the DVD and copy an individual file you could just create an ISO image and extract the file with any program that can open ISO images.